# My Ionic/Capacitor app is not asking for my phone's location and gives me the default location I set

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

I'm using Vanilla JS with Ionic for a small mobile development project I had to do as an assignment, I had to make a map using Leaflet but it works wonderfully the thing is that I have a function that saves the position for the device and saves it as asociative array called UserPosition for me to use later, but not only it does not ask my phone for permission for my location, even if i forcefully give it permissions it does not save my location, here is the function i'm talking about. I need help to know as to why this is happening, thanks.
PS: I call the function as soon as the app boots

```
function LoadUserPosition() {
    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
        const loadCurrentPosition = async () => {
            const result = await Capacitor.Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ timeout: 3000 });
            if (result.coords && result.coords.latitude) {
                userPosition = {
                    latitude: result.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: result.coords.longitude
                }
            }
        };
        loadCurrentPosition();
    } else {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function (pos) {
            if (pos && pos.coords && pos.coords.latitude) {
                userPosition = {
                    latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: pos.coords.longitude
                };
            }
        },
        function () {
            //Nothing because i already have a default position for the user
        });
    }
}
```

When making the build for my app I changed the permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml to ask for the permissions of location of my phone

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.loca3on.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Your code smells a little like you are not waiting for those async operations to complete before consuming userPosition.